# Angular - `ng-content` doesn't have access to hoster?

Tags: javascript, angular

Simplification :

My `app-root` element has this template :

```
 <div *ngFor="let item of [1,2,3,4,5,6]">
      <card *appDelay="100 * item" [num]="item">
        {{item}}
      </card>
    </div>
```

It uses a structural directive which does all the work.

[*Plunker : The `appDelay`  create dynamic component with a delay + sequentials numbers.*](https://plnkr.co/edit/80AGn8bR4CiyH0ceP8ws?p=preview)

It does it with  `this.viewContainerRef.createEmbeddedView`

But now ( for learning purpose) I want **not** to use `{{item}}` but to send the `item` to the `card` via `@input` property named `num`:

[image]

Obviously I've already added

```
  @Input()
  num : number = 0;
```

to the `CardComponent` component And also added context to the `createEmbeddedView` method :

```
 this.viewContainerRef.createEmbeddedView(this.templateRef,{$implicit: {num: time} });
```

**Question**

It seems that i'm trying to do it via two directions :

1) context to the template
2) `@input` variable

But none works. ( I don't see the numbers).

How can I set the number myself ( context || @input) ?

[**Plunker**](https://plnkr.co/edit/0nL39wCMGwVlLtISTpZK?p=preview)

Comment: Even if the input isn't working I'd have expected `0` to display.

Comment: @isherwood https://plnkr.co/edit/80AGn8bR4CiyH0ceP8ws?p=preview - this is the example that works with numbers - but not as I wanted in question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
<card *appDelay="500 * item; let num">
   {{num}}
</card>
```

is equivalent

```
<ng-template [appDelay]="500 * item" let-num="$implicit">
  <card>
       {{num}}
  </card>
</ng-template>
```

and inside directive

```
this.viewContainerRef.createEmbeddedView(this.templateRef,{$implicit:time/500 });
```

**[Plunker Example](https://plnkr.co/edit/9HOF9SxxbV08Vu78Vvm7?p=preview)**

Comment: I will not repeat the same answer. ( which is : Thank you very much  like always). :-)

Comment: Why sending@input AND setting context like I did - none helped ?

Comment: Input `[num]="item"` doesn't create context

Comment: besides - what if I want to send 2 parameters to the appDelay ? here you send one value and divided to get the number. What if I want to send just an ADDITIONAL arbitary number ?

Comment: mmm. It seems that `#cartComp` is mandatory  (and not used). why ?

Comment: `num` in `[num]="item"` is not template variable. it's @Input, you can't access to it inside template. Only through component instance that i got via template reference variable `#cardComp`

Comment: Only now that I see this : `appDelayNum` which is `appDelay__X__`. wow

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/160337/discussion-between-royi-namir-and-yurzui).

Answer (score 1):

Okey so here is what I would do:

https://plnkr.co/edit/Qw9RFNWz18B9UQ6PWRfD?p=preview

1. You send in a template as content to you card component. `ng-template`
2. In your card component you get a reference to that template with `@ContentChild`
3. Use a `ng-container` and `[ngTemplateOutlet]` to render your template in your card component
4. To get the input "num" available to the template use `[ngTemplateOutletContext]` and set the variable `$implicit` to num, ($implicit let you use any variable name you want on your template with let-yourVaiableName)
5. On your template add `let-num` to get a reference to the template context variable
6. Print it out with {{num}}

Hope this helps :)

Sorry could not get code inlining to work :/

Comment: Works. but what's wrong with (reason) with my code ? BTW I've noticed that context for the template is redundant in your solution. (removed it and still works)

Comment: The {{num}} you are using refers to content in the current Component "main". By using a template it is rendered/instantiated inside of the card-component and gets a hold of that variable instead with the `let-num`